# Show different image each day from the list of array in Thunkable

Tags: mobile, thunkable

I'm trying to develop an app using Thunkable classic.

I planned to make a list of images (99 images) and show different image each day in order.

I have added timer but how do I make it show a different one each day?

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by date? Can you explain this date feature in more details please?

Comment: As date change, the image should change. Similar to this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.almisbah.yaadehaq

Comment: may be set an js interval and inside interval function perform your stuff?